# How to make discord.py bot delete its own message after some time?

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I have this code in Python:

```py
import discord
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(channels_id_where_i_want_to_send_message))
    response = f'Hello {member}!'
    await channel.send(response)

client.run('bots_token')
```

And I want the bot to delete its own message.  For example, after one minute, how do I do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a better way than what **Dean Ambros** and **Dom** suggested, you can simply add the kwarg `delete_after` in `.send`

```py
await ctx.send('whatever', delete_after=60.0)
```

[reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context%20send#discord.ext.commands.Context.send)

Answer (score 3):

Before we do anything, we want to import asyncio. This can let us wait set amounts of time in the code.

```py
import asyncio
```

Start by defining the message you send. That way we can come back to it for later.

```py
msg = await channel.send(response)
```

Then, we can wait a set amount of time using asyncio. The time in the parentheses is counted in seconds, so one minute would be 60, two 120, and so on.

```py
await asyncio.sleep(60)
```

Next, we actually delete the message that we originally sent.

```py
await msg.delete()
```

So, altogether your code would end up looking something like this:

```py
import discord
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    channel = client.get_channel(123...))
    response = f'Hello {member}!'
    msg = await channel.send(response) # defining msg
    await asyncio.sleep(60) # waiting 60 seconds
    await msg.delete() # Deleting msg
```

You can also read up more in this [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=delete%20message#discord.Message.delete). Hope this helped!

Comment: I had to change 
```py
async def on_voice_state_update(member)
```
to
```py
async def on_voice_state_update(member, after, before)
```
Because it said:
TypeError: on_voice_state_update() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
But now everything works just fine, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be too complicated. Hope it helped.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import time
import asyncio
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@commands.command(name="test")
async def test(ctx):
    message = 'Hi'
    msg = await ctx.send(message)
    await ctx.message.delete() # Deletes the users message
    await asyncio.sleep(5) # you want it to wait.
    await msg.delete() # Deletes the message the bot sends.
 
client.add_command(test)
client.run(' bot_token')
```