# How do I make the bot delete its embed message after a while?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

Good afternoon, I want the bot to delete its embed message in a minute, how do I implement it, here is the code

```
    @client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_any_role(819292703589269514,817408828500213860,817408830240456754,817643991331766283)
async def clear (ctx, amount : int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount + 1)
    emb = discord.Embed (title = 'Удалено {} сообщений!'.format(amount), colour = discord.Color.gold())
    await ctx.send(embed = emb)
    await asyncio.sleep(15)
    await emb.delete()
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? You have the solution in your code, just change `15` to `60`?

Comment: yes, I will change it to 60, I just tested it so that it would be deleted faster, but it is not deleted, I do not get any errors

Comment: Have you tried: `await ctx.send(embed=emb, delete_after=60)` without the `asyncio` event?

Comment: No, I'll try it now

Comment: I also added a way how you can use your `await xxx.delete()` function in my answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Discord.py) How to make bot delete his own message after some time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65417166/discord-py-how-to-make-bot-delete-his-own-message-after-some-time)

Answer (score 0):

*If anyone else has the problem here is an answer:*

Please take care of the correct indentation, there are too many spaces in some places.

You can also use an `delete_after` "event" instead of your `emb.delete()`.

**It would look like this:**

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_any_role(819292703589269514, 817408828500213860, 817408830240456754, 817643991331766283)
async def clear(ctx, amount: int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount + 1)
    emb = discord.Embed(title='Удалено {} сообщений!'.format(amount), color=discord.Color.gold())
    await ctx.send(embed=emb, delete_after=60) # delet_after added
```

**If you want to use your method you have to define the embed you are sending:**

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_any_role(819292703589269514, 817408828500213860, 817408830240456754, 817643991331766283)
async def clear(ctx, amount: int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount + 1)
    emb = discord.Embed(title='Удалено {} сообщений!'.format(amount), colour=discord.Color.gold())
    test1 = await ctx.send(embed=emb) # We define the embed as test1
    await asyncio.sleep(15)
    await test1.delete() # test1 (Embed) gets deleted
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple to do so. You just need to define a variable which sends the embed. Here's the code -

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_any_role(819292703589269514,817408828500213860,817408830240456754,817643991331766283)
async def clear (ctx, amount : int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount + 1)
    emb = discord.Embed (title = 'Удалено {} сообщений!'.format(amount), colour = discord.Color.gold())
    sendemb = await ctx.send(embed = emb)
    await asyncio.sleep(15)
    await sendemb.delete()
```

So here all I did was name the embed sending (sendemb) and after sleeping for 15 seconds, it deletes it!

Hope I helped you.