# How do you make a bot that sends a welcome embed and deletes the embed after a few seconds in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here's my code but it seems like it doesn't work. I'm so sorry but, I'm still a newbie but, I would very much appreciate your help and critics.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix,
                      intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_message_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(channelid)
    count = member.guild.member_count
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Welcome to {member.guild.name}", description=f"Hello there {member.name}!", footer=count) 
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url) 

    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    time.sleep(5)
    message.delete(embed)
```

Comment: `time.sleep(5)` is blocking you should never use it, instead use `asyncio.sleep(5)` (made for asynchronous programming).
You also forget to await your `message.delete`.
So I recommend to just add the [delete_after](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send) argument so you should have `await channel.send(embed=embed, delete_after=5)` (delay in seconds), remove the sleep and the delete and it should work as expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make discord.py bot delete its own message after some time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65417166/how-to-make-discord-py-bot-delete-its-own-message-after-some-time)

Comment: I quite tried your advice about changing it to `await channel.send(embed-embed, delete_after=5)` but, it still doesn't appear in the channel I assigned it to send even after a member already joined the server.

Comment: Oh Sorry! It finally worked. TYSM For the help and critics.

Answer (score 0):

The correct discord event to catch that a person joins your discord is:

```
async def on_member_join(member: discord.Member):
```

rather than `on_message_join`

To easily delete the message you can first make it a string:

```
msg = await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

then get it's id by:

```
msg_id = msg.id
```

then fetch it:

```
msg_todel = await channel.fetch_message(int(msg_id))
```

then delete it:

```
await msg_todel.delete()
```

Comment: `channel.send` [returns a message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send), not a string, so steps 3. and 4. are unnecessary.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs yeah you are right, I also did not know about `delete_after` which is faster anyways. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `delete_after=seconds`, this exactly what's your wanted

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix,
                      intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_message_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(channelid)
    count = member.guild.member_count
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Welcome to {member.guild.name}", description=f"Hello there {member.name}!", footer=count) 
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url) 

    await channel.send(embed=embed, delete_after=5)
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the [discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=edit#discord.Message.edit), you could edit the message object after 5 seconds and then just set the new `embed` parameter to `None`, this seems to be what you're after here.

Below is a way you can alter your code to do this.

```py
import discord
import asyncio # You will need to import this as well
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix,
                      intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_message_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(channelid)
    count = member.guild.member_count
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Welcome to {member.guild.name}", description=f"Hello there {member.name}!", footer=count) 
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url) 

    message_object = await channel.send(embed=embed) # You can save the message sent by attaching it to a variable. You don't need to send more calls to refetch it.
    
    '''
    time.sleep(5) <--- You should not use time.sleep() as it will stop your entire bot from doing anything else during these 5 seconds.

    Use asyncio.sleep() as a better alternative. Does the same thing as time.sleep() but other functions of your bot will still function, this is called a  blocking function.
    '''

    asyncio.sleep(5)
    
    await message_object.edit(embed = None)
```

Unless you want the entire message deleted, then you can just use `delete_after` in order to obtain this.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix,
                      intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_message_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(channelid)
    count = member.guild.member_count
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Welcome to {member.guild.name}", description=f"Hello there {member.name}!", footer=count) 
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url) 

    await channel.send(embed=embed, delete_after = 5) # Just add this parameter at the end.
```

Comment: You can't use a keyword argument and then a positional argument in your last line, that would raise an error.